# IwebHostEnvironment interface

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-mvc

I have used IwebHostEnvironment in my code. IWebHostEnvironment is an interface used to provide info about hosting & can get data about path from it

Why can I take an instance from it and inject it like I was injecting a _db without registering it in ConfigureServices method like I register a Db context?

```
public class ProductController : Controller
{
    private readonly App_DbContext _db;
    private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _webHostEnvironment;
    public ProductController(App_DbContext db,IWebHostEnvironment webHostEnvironment)
    {
        _db = db;
        _webHostEnvironment = webHostEnvironment;
    }
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        IEnumerable<Product> products= _db.Product;
        return View(products);
    }
}
```

this is configure services Method

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<App_DbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
    services.AddControllersWithViews();
}
```

Comment: The framework will register the IWebHostEnvironment as part of its start up flow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agree with @Nkosi, you can refer to [this section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-6.0#framework-provided-services), `IWebHostEnvironment` is one of the framework-registered services.

[image]